# Href attribute not working in Sitecore

Tags: html, anchor, sitecore

Anchor Tag is fetching the Url which i have to navigate ( validated from right click -> open in new Tab ) on but not working directly on clicking the link.

The Url is fetched from a repeater which is reverting a list of URLs in Sitecore.

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="Repeater2">
   <itemtemplate>  
      <a href="<%#ECMLibrary.SitecoreLibrary.GetItemURL(((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem))%>" >
         <sc:text id="txt" runat="server" item="<%#Container.DataItem%>" field="Title"></sc:text>
      </a>
      <br />
   </itemtemplate>
 </asp:repeater>
```

And .cs file for the same is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = SitecoreLibrary.GetItem(SitecoreItemID.TopmenuItemID); 
     List<Item> lstItems = new List<Item>(); 

      if (item != null) 
      { 
           lstItems = SitecoreLibrary.GetMultiListItems(item, "Menu1"); 

           Repeater1.DataSource = lstItems; 
           Repeater1.DataBind(); 
      }
 }
```

Comment: I don`t quite get your question. Have you inspected the html to see what is there ? Also you seem to use some kind of library (ECMLibrary) and we have no idea what the code is.

Comment: ECMLIbrary is the custom Library. Actually i am simplying intending to open a new webpage on click of <a> through href. This <a> is fetching the URL right. Even if i am navigating from it by reight click option it works , but not on a single click.Althogh on hover also it is displaying the correct URL, over which it has to redirect, at lower left of the Chrome Browser. thus it has the URL but onclick its not navigating on that.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a css problem ? Are you getting any errors in the developer console when you try to click the links ? Your code seems fine if the library is fetching the URL correct.

Comment: Yes its not that because over the same link if i right click and go to the option Open in New Tab then i reach the desired webPage. No errors in console.

Comment: Well if the link is rendered correctly it doesn't seem to be a backend related issue.

Comment: Yeah , click event on the <a> is not responding . Dont know Why

Comment: Are you in `Page Editor` mode? Can you check in `preview` mode?

Comment: Yeah i am checking it in Preview mode only. Over the Browser

Comment: Sounds like you have a Javascript event handler attached to it which is causing it to do something else different from standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question and comments since it sounds like your issue is that you want to open the link in a new tab on click and for that all you need to do is add target="_blank" to the anchor tag, which is too obvious. If the click itself is not firing then there must be some js code hijacking the click. Is there a way to access the page publicly.

Comment: target="_blank" is for opening in New Tab . But i am not intending to open it in a new Tab. Indeed i intend to open it over a single mouse click over the Same Page, which is not responding. But for testing purposes i checked by right click - open in new tab. Regarding Javascript code i will Check once more for any conflicts over a same element